# TFS 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 Syntax

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2017

Our company is stuck on TFS 2013 due to Adobe's RoboHelp software only working with that as a maximum version. We are looking to migrate to .NET 4.6 from 4.0 and VS 2017 - As such we can use new framework featuers (such as Async / Await) and language features (Like Tuples).

Unfortunately our team build is failing when building a test project with the upgraded stuff and I assume this is because it's pointing at the 4.0 MSBuild.

I've installed VS2017 (Compiler and .NET 4.6 targeting pack). I have done some research on the topic but TFS 2013 + VS 2017 seems an oddly specific combination. I did however find that I need to change the ToolsVersion to 14.0 which I have done.

MSBuild then shows me that the maximum ToolsVersion I can have is 12.0, which again makes me think I'm using an old MSBUild. More research lead me to the ToolsPath property which I have set to **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"**. However this still gives me the same error.

How do I go about getting VS 2017 projects to build on TFS 2013? I presume I need some kind of MSBuild path changing but the ones I have tried so far just don't seem to cater for the new syntax.

Comment: You can use tools higher than 12.0 in TFS 2013. Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72607172/2718518).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for anybody else that comes across this issue - There are potentially multiple MSBuild tasks within the build process template, I happened to have two and as soon as I changed the ToolPath on the second task to the full MSBuild path, my project started to build.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark your reply as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: Hi, how do you change de toolpath in TFS2013? Thanks!